# Export to Excel, open, enable editing and all the formulas change

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have an important spreadsheet I have created using Google Docs. This is over many tabs pulling numbers into the first tab. It all works well in Google Spreadsheets but I need to download it.

When I download it as Excel and open it it shows OK but asks me to enable editing / saving. As soon as I do this the data changes on the sheet and all my formulas are screwed.

Can anyone help?

I am new to this so I hope I have posted in the correct area :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you already own excel ?

To export a Google Sheets file to Excel, open the Sheet, go to File > Download As and select .xlsx.